# Why all zip files should be marked as executable?

Tags: executable, zip, extract

I can extract any .zip file by right clicking on it and choosing `Extract here`. I'm also able to open any .rar .tar.gz and etc files without extracting them (access its inside files by opening the .rar file)
but I can't open any .zip files by clicking on them.
I get an error like this:

```
The file '/home/rasool/Desktop/Samlpes.zip' is not marked as executable.  If this was downloaded or copied from an untrusted source, it may be dangerous to run.  For more details, read about the executable bit.
```

I have to extract them first! I want to open .zip files without extracting them.
I know how to make a file executable, but I don't want to do it each time I open a .zip file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip files should not be executable. Something has gone wrong.

Right click on a zip file and click "Properties". You will see a "Open with" tab. Choose the "File Roller" archive manager, and press the "Set as default" button. Next time you double click a zip file, the archive manager will be opened.